# PHP OOP - Require or Extend

Tags: php, oop, coding-style

I was wondering if there is any major different in the following, and whether one is more 'standard' than the other:

```
<?php

class Account extends Database {

    public function myMethod()
    {
        // Do something
    }

}

?>
```

or

```
<?php

require('database.class.php');

class Account {

    public function myMethod()
    {
        // Do something
    }

}

?>
```

Cheers :)

**Edit:**

This question actually relates to a tutorial series I have been following which describes the above two methods - which didn't make any clear sense.

So thank you for the constructive answers on clearing that one up!

Comment: You're comparing apple and orange now.

Comment: Does former one ever work? (say, without autoload)?

Comment: these two structures have nothing to do with each other. I'd say you have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php for some basic concepts.

Comment: I think you may want to review [`extends`](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) a bit.

Comment: I would write my usual diatribe about Composition over Inheritance, but I think that may be going over the head of this question.  In short, they are not the same by any means...

Comment: It actually came from a tutorial using database connections in OOP - hense I got confused myself! I think thats at least cleared that question up for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two completely separate language constructs.

Your first example deals with inheritance. Basically, you already have a class called `Database`, but you want to have a specialized version of that class to handle accounts. Rather than build a brand new `Account` class and copy/paste all the functionality you already have in your `Database` class, you simply tell PHP that you want to use the existing `Database` class as a baseline. You create any account-specific functionality in the new `Account` class, and anything database-related comes automatically. This is assuming, of course, that you have some way of specifying where the `Database` class is defined - for example, a `require` declaration at the top of the class, or an `__autoload()` or `spl_autoload_register()` function call defining a way to find and locate the file containing the `Database` class.

In your second example, your database-related code is completely separated from your `Account` class. They're completely distinct entities, and if you wanted to do anything database-related in your `Account` class, you would have to explicitly instantiate a new `Database` object within that class (or pass it *to* that class, or one of its functions, as a parameter.

Basically, `extends` helps define *what* a class is, whereas `require` shows *where* a class definition (or other code) is stored.

Comment: thank you. It actually came from an example listed on a tutorial and it confused me thinking that they weren’t the same. So thank you for the explanation helping clear things up rather than shooting me down with the firing squad

Comment: @lethalMango: You're welcome. We all have to start somewhere. I think a lot of the reaction you saw from others was simply that they were slightly annoyed that you hadn't looked up the definitions of `extends` and `require` in [the manual](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/index.php) before asking here. There's a lot of information to be found there, and it's easy to find. As a tip, you can often go to the URL `php.net/<function_name>` and the site will redirect you to the correct page. It doesn't always work perfectly for language constructs, but it always works great when given a function name.

Answer (score 2):

Both code snippets aren't even equivalent.

The first declares Account to extend Database, a is-a relation.

In the second code snippet, you are simply saying that you [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) 'database.class.php' ... and that neither has anything to do with OO, nor defines a is-relation from Account to Database.

Answer (score 1):

Both are completely different in first one class is inherited by another class but in the second one the class is included in your script only.

Means if you `extend` all the public and protected methods are available in your derived class and you can create object of derived class and can use methods with derived class's object.

But in the second method the class is included in your script and require this class it's own method and work independently.

Answer (score 1):

The first means you create a new class, which has all the functionality of Database class and those you implement.

The second means that you create a new class, but it doesn't have Database functionality since it's not extending it. If you need database access in your Account class, you can create an instance in constructor, or pass already created instance as constructor parameter.

It's hard to say what is more standard, since it depends on what You actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To put it in most simple terms:-

`require` or `include` is structural programming.

`extends` is object oriented